# Realtime digital rising and falling edge ploting on sound signals

Tags: python, matplotlib, real-time-updates

Hello i need both sound singnal and a digital signal on the same subplots. for 1st and secong plots are sound signals and i can read it very fast. I need a 3rd digital digital signal to see. In this case when i press key button i need a digital HIGH. when i wrote the python code 3rd signal (key press) is not changing in the middle of the plot. i mean i cant see the rising and falling edges during the plot. how can i solve it?

```
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import time
plt.style.use('bmh')

BUFFER = 1024*4 # number of data points to read at a time
SAMPLERATE = 44100 # time resolution of the recording device (Hz)

p = pyaudio.PyAudio() # instantiate PyAudio
stream=p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,channels=1,rate=SAMPLERATE,input=True,
              frames_per_buffer=BUFFER) # use default input device to open audio stream
pause = False
key = False

# üç satır bir sütün üç adet ax ekseni hazırla, fig class ı çağır
fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(3,1,sharex=True)

#x-y veri dizilerini ayrı ayrı diziler oluştur
xdata, ydata, ydata2, ydata3= [], [], [], []

#ax1, ax2 ve ax3 ü çiz 2D obje olarak ln, ln2 ve ln3'e boş olarak döndür
ln, = ax1.plot([], [], lw=1)
ln2, = ax2.plot([], [],lw=1)
ln3, = ax3.step([],[], lw=2) #yükslen ve alçalan kenarı göstermek için .step

# xdata zaman ekseni olarak buffer kadar eşit aralıkta dizi oluştur.
xdata = np.linspace(0, BUFFER-1, BUFFER)

# methods for animation
def init():
    ax1.set_xlim(0, BUFFER-1)       # ax1 x ekseni sınırla
    ax1.set_ylim(-100000, 100000)   #ax1 y ekseni sınırla 100 000
    ax2.set_ylim(-10000, 10000)   # ax2 ye ekseni sınırla 10 000
    ax3.set_ylim(-0.5,1.5)              # ax3 0-1 arası dijital
    return ln,ln2,ln3,    # Artist objelerin geri döndür

def animate(i):
    ydata = np.frombuffer(stream.read(BUFFER), dtype=np.int16)
    #ydata2 = np.frombuffer(stream.read(BUFFER), dtype=np.int16)
    ydata3= key
    
    print("ydata3",ydata3)
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)       # xdata ve ydata yı ln 2D objesinde birleştir
    ln2.set_data(xdata, ydata / 2) # ydata 10 a böl
    ln3.set_data(xdata, ydata3)
    return ln,ln2,ln3,

def onClick(event):
    global pause
    pause ^= True
    if pause==False:
        anim.resume()
    else:
        anim.pause()
    #print(pause)

def onKey(event):
    global key
    #time.sleep(1)
    key ^= True
    
    
#mouse klik oluşunca onClick fonksiyonuna git
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onClick)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', onKey)
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, interval=20,
       blit=True)

plt.show()

# stop and close the audio stream
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

[key press LOW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qSTN.png)

[key press HIGH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWTH0.png)

Comment: You don't keep any data on when the key was pressed. Do you just want to see rising/falling edge always in the middle of the plot? Or do want to see the edge when it happened relative to the audio? In the latter case you will have to save a timestamp in the `onKey()` function and somehow get timestamps for the audio as well.
In the former case, try setting `keychanged=True` in `onKey`, setting it to `False` after the plot and do `ln3.set_data([xdata[0], xdata[0]/2+xdata[-1]/2 , xdata[-1]], [~key, ~key, key, key])` instead of what you had `if keychanged`

Comment: Thanks for reply Koen. I Just need to see rusing and falling edges with the same auidio signal. Later i ll try to do this: When i press the key i ll start audio streaming. And i want to see the timing difference in the subplot. I mean key press Will be trigger for streaming. One axes for digital trigger the other axes for audio streaming wave